# How to find a crash at start happening for App Review team, but not on my Mac?

Tags: macos, crash, app-store, submit

I'm trying to publish one of my games on the Mac AppStore, but I got the following report from the App Review team :

> Here is how we found this crash:
>   The app crashes on second launch of the app.

and here the crash log :

```
Process:         Tennis Elbow Manager [19919]
Path:            /Applications/Tennis Elbow Manager.app/Contents/MacOS/Tennis Elbow Manager
Identifier:      com.managames.Tennis-Elbow-Manager
Version:         1.9.38 (38)
App Item ID:     0
App External ID: 0
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [160]
User ID:         201

Date/Time:       2013-03-06 16:22:44.968 -0800
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.2 (12C54)
Report Version:  10

Crashed Thread:  1  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.managames.Tennis-Elbow-Manager  0x000e3214 0x6b000 + 492052
1   ???                             0x492e5245 0 + 1227772485

Thread 1 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9a6979ae kevent + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x9775dc71 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 993
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x9775d7a9 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 53

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9a6970ee __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9105d04c _pthread_workq_return + 45
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9105ce19 _pthread_wqthread + 448
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x91044cca start_wqthread + 30

Thread 1 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):
  eax: 0x00000004  ebx: 0xb0102700  ecx: 0xb01025ac  edx: 0x9a6979ae
  edi: 0x00000000  esi: 0x9775d8a1  ebp: 0xb0102718  esp: 0xb01025ac
   ss: 0x00000023  efl: 0x00000247  eip: 0x9a6979ae   cs: 0x0000000b
   ds: 0x00000023   es: 0x00000023   fs: 0x00000023   gs: 0x0000000f
  cr2: 0x0269e000
Logical CPU: 0

Binary Images:
   0x6b000 -   0x192ff3 +com.managames.Tennis-Elbow-Manager (1.9.38 - 38) <B6D93CA3-ADB3-3C94-AB00-25C63C74250A> /Applications/Tennis Elbow Manager.app/Contents/MacOS/Tennis Elbow Manager
  0x38b000 -   0x3d6fc0 +SDL (1.2.14 - 1.2.14) <84ABD881-2313-3168-889A-EDEA4EBAA928> /Applications/Tennis Elbow Manager.app/Contents/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/A/SDL
  0x3e9000 -   0x400ff7 +org.libsdl.SDL-mixer (1.2.12 - 1.2.12) <879D26B7-6FC0-32FD-BA92-484F89677158> /Applications/Tennis Elbow Manager.app/Contents/Frameworks/SDL_mixer.framework/Versions/A/SDL_mixer
  0x433000 -   0x437ffb +org.libsdl.SDL-image (1.2.12 - 1.2.12) <C8A71F96-C7E3-3290-A886-ECA7994E847D> /Applications/Tennis Elbow Manager.app/Contents/Frameworks/SDL_image.framework/Versions/A/SDL_image
  0x441000 -   0x46fff7 +mikmod (3.1.10r2 - 3.1.12) <484ED43A-1C22-DF87-240A-594F8F37B9BE> /Applications/Tennis Elbow Manager.app/Contents/Frameworks/SDL_mixer.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/mikmod.framework/Versions/A/mikmod
  0x484000 -   0x4bbffa +smpeg (0.0.1d1) <900C8FCF-8E29-3941-AE32-14F3208DBAE8> /Applications/Tennis Elbow Manager.app/Contents/Frameworks/SDL_mixer.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/smpeg.framework/Versions/A/smpeg
  0x4e5000 -   0x4e8ff4 +org.xiph.ogg (1.1.4 - 1.1.4) <B4E7F924-42D6-3E2A-9EF0-E55CD71BF308> /Applications/Tennis Elbow Manager.app/Contents/Frameworks/SDL_mixer.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Ogg.framework/Versions/A/Ogg
  0x4ef000 -   0x672ff2 +org.xiph.vorbis (1.2.3 - 1.2.3) <F9FCDD01-A9B1-35AD-B1DB-DE0C8F347869> /Applications/Tennis Elbow Manager.app/Contents/Frameworks/SDL_mixer.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Vorbis.framework/Versions/A/Vorbis
  0x6a6000 -   0x6eeff4 +FLAC (1.2.1 - 1.2.1) <5F0B6D50-0DFC-357C-89EA-CA56EDEC997D> /Applications/Tennis Elbow Manager.app/Contents/Frameworks/SDL_mixer.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/FLAC.framework/Versions/A/FLAC
[...]
```

Full log is here => http://a1.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple/v4/da/b2/03/dab203db-b866-3d55-8ea9-88df1de4c285/temp..cqdsammn.crash

```
(gdb) info line *0x000e3214
```

gives :

```
No line number information available for address 0xe3214 <_ZN10CSysCursorD1Ev+2958>
```

The game is working well on my OSX 10.8.2, both with my account & a guest account, I can launch it many times without issue.
The crash seems to happen right on start-up before it gets into any of my functions (ie: it's still probably in the main() or even the start).
I looked for identical crash "Thread 1 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager" on Google & I could find a few almost identical reports, mainly about a Skype version, but that didn't teach me much...

So now I'm kinda stuck, and my only idea is to resubmit hoping it was a rare random crash, but I doubt it's the best move...

Anyone would have a better idea ? Thanks in advance for any answer ! :)

I'm using : SDL 1.2.15, SDL_Image 1.2.12, SDL_Mixer 1.2.12,  roddi's ValidateStoreReceipt from https://github.com/roddi/ValidateStoreReceipt .

Comment: Have you symbolicated the crash report?

Comment: as shown above, I tried with gdb, but it gave me the error quoted, I'm not sure why...